# Got EOS from element "pipeline0" on gst fbdevsink

Tags: framebuffer, gstreamer

I'm trying to forward video file to the framebuffer on my device that has no X. I'm using `gstreamer` with `fbdevsink` plugin.

- When I test it with

  ```
  gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! fbdevsink
  ```

  it works perfectly.
- However when I try to open any video file on my device with command

  ```
  gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=right_top1.mp4 ! fbdevsink
  ```

  it stops working immediately with output

  ```
  Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
  Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
  Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
  Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
  New clock: GstSystemClock
  Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
  Execution ended after 0:00:00.006988697
  Setting pipeline to NULL ...
  Freeing pipeline ...
  ```

I cannot figure out what is going on, because even when I add debugging (`-v --gst-debug-level=2`) output is the same.

If it matters, I'm working on Nvidia Jetson Nano with Yocto OS.

Do you guys have any idea how to resolve or just debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally drop `gstreamer` and used `ffmpeg` without any more issues.

Command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 1000000 -i <RTSP_stream_addr> -pix_fmt bgra -loglevel
```